# Google Voice API for web apps?

Tags: web-applications, browser-plugin, google-voice

I'd like to allow users of my site to have a list of contacts and click a button beside a user to initiate a Google Voice chat session, exactly like I can in Gmail. I'd like to be able to detect whether the Google Voice browser plugin is installed and use it if it is installed.

Is there a way to interact with the plugin as described? I'm open to similar solutions. I'd like to not have to route voice server through my server and let the user go directly through Google's Voice servers.

FWIW, I'm using Ruby/Rails for my backend.

Answer (score 1):

There are a 2 gems , just search in http://rubygems.org/

Also, here are some useful links:
http://posttopic.com/topic/google-voice-add-on-development#post-27
http://starrhorne.com/posts/custom_google_voice_widget_rails_and_jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not Ruby, but [here](https://github.com/aaronpk/Google-Voice-PHP-API) is a web PHP API.

[This](http://code.google.com/p/phpgooglevoice) is another one.

However the plugin.... I don't think so. :( sorry.